# Moderators should not hold the question if they do not understand science of Statistics

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99376/how-do-i-add-this-p-value-to-normal-probability-plot-in-minitab) was about Minitab but the [moderator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) made a hold on the question because he didn't understand it. He has a lack on the topic of [assumptions for regression analysis](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/testing.htm) (iv: "normality of the error distribution"). This is why he is asking

> Please tell us how the five statistics given in the table ought to be represented by graphical elements in this plot. (How to do that for a p-value is particularly mysterious, so please pay special attention to that .)

in the comment section. I find it really funny that he is moderating the site in this way, he can moderate but if he doesn't understand some basic topics about Statistics he should not block questions.

If you look at his [CV](http://www.quantdec.com/quals/cv.pdf) you will see that he has no education in Statistics, and he is making fun of me (I'm a 4th year Statistics student).

Comment: I am sorry that you ever got the impression I was making fun of you; that certainly was never the intent. In recognition of and deference to your demonstrably superior education, I would like to invite you on behalf of the entire community to participate more actively on our site by answering questions (especially the ones I cannot understand) and becoming a candidate during the next moderator election. We cordially welcome knowledgeable, well-spoken, friendly, and supportive people to join us in curating our site and helping others learn and appreciate statistics.

Comment: @whuber, you made a block over my question because you thought that the information given in the box is not related with those dots and line. So you thought that my question is absurd and doesn't make any sense. And then I had to explain that this is commonly used technique. Then you get offended and keep my question on hold.

Comment: @whuber, you yourself, you are not following the rules http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask "avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion" http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/looking-for-good-introductory-treatment-of-meta-analysis

Comment: Are you seriously saying that @whuber does not understand statistics?  That is very amusing.

Comment: Dear Ilhan, I am not in the least offended by your question. Please know that it is not "blocked." Its "on hold" status provides you an opportunity to change it so that you can get better and more answers faster than otherwise. It takes only five community members--or just one other moderator--to re-open it. The *constructive* option available to you is to clarify your question. Your continuing attacks, by means of comments here and in the original thread, will likely only embarrass you and nobody wants that.  I have asked the other moderators to take over here, so I will be silent.

Comment: Because your question was either just plain wrong (because those numbers should not go in a probability plot) or so badly worded that neither he nor I could understand it.  The idea that @whuber does not understand the assumptions of linear regression is ludicrous.

Comment: @PeterFlom, the title and the information in the box is given by Minitab, not me or someone else.

Comment: And why do you suppose Minitab puts those variables in a box and not on the graph? Do you suppose they, too, don't know what they are doing? Those numbers belong in a box (or in text) not on the graph. There is no place to put them on the graph.

Comment: @PeterFlom, it is placed by Minitab.

Comment: @PeterFlom, see yourself http://goo.gl/lDKq5C if you don't believe me.

Comment: The plot as produced by Minitab is fine. They all place the information in a box. Not on the graph.

Comment: @PeterFlom, I want that box, whether on right or in or on on doesn't matter. When I plot I don't get that info box http://i.imgur.com/nWcU3BK.png that is my problem.

Comment: The box is there in your output!  What are you asking? Maybe your whole question is unclear.

Comment: By box I mean that box which has p-value, mean, and standard deviation. I don't have it here http://i.imgur.com/nWcU3BK.png

Comment: This (new) remark is simply misguided! A cooling-off period may be appropriate at this point.

Comment: @iihan is insulting multiple moderators. I think it's time for him to leave.

Comment: The ridiculous insult in the title doesn't bode well. I suggest you revise it to something that at least suggests some contact with reality. My own knowledge of statistics is pretty broad, but whuber's is considerably broader (and deeper) than mine. Every single moderator has (far) more than sufficient knowledge to carry out their duties. If you can't discuss your concern with the decision to place your question on hold in a more mature fashion, you should consider taking your questions to a forum that tolerates insult and innuendo. StackExchange isn't that place.

Answer (score 12):

**Your question is off-topic.** Any moderator would have put your question on hold, waiting further clarifications from your part.

Your question is clearly not about visualizing data; you are just asking how to customize a regression diagnostic plot generated by a particular statistical package, i.e. putting a box with some numbers near a probability plot, as the comment thread and [revision history](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/99376/revisions) of your post suggest. In comparison, the [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97774/graphing-and-analyzing-probit-regression) you referred to in one of your comment is about plotting and interpreting the results of a Probit model, that is how to convey meaningful information from a regression model and what conclusion can be drawn from model's output (this is completely independent of the software used for that particular analysis), which is perfectly on-topic here.

Beside what is [on-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Cross Validated, there's a section that reads [Be nice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). In that respect, **public *ad hominem* allegations are inappropriate on Stack Exchange**: They are useless, counter-productive, and they will only serve to discredit your arguments. In my experience--and this does not limit to Stack Exchange or public communities--constructive and respectful discussions are more likely to lead to positive feedback and consensual decision.

In this particular case, you already got helpful comments: the very first comment was posted to help see if there was possibly a statistical inquiry requiring statistical or data visualization expertise behind your original post. As it appeared that it was purely off-topic, you were kindly suggested to refer to Minitab help or our own software-related resources. Then you raised the issue on our Meta seeking input from other users about your problem, while targeting a particular person in very negative and rude terms. It is simply not a constructive behavior: Moderators and community members are here to help as benevolent contributors, and I do not think anyone really likes to be challenged in such a way.

Comment: Not having unconstactive moderators is constrictive and all you do here is protecting your friend.

Comment: ihan - chl and whuber don't even live in the same continent. (I live in a third continent, and have never met either; my judgements are based solely on observing their actions over several years). Both whuber and chl are consistently very patient and fair, and both are highly knowledgeable. You do yourself no favors by insulting at least three moderators by my count, none of whom seem to be doing anything but what their job as moderators needs them to do. Periodically I disagree with moderators, yet they are always willing to listen and revise their actions if there's even a hint of a mistake.

Comment: ... but there's no suggestion of any mistake in this case. The question requires clarification and a change of focus to meet the community standards that are generally applied. Your best action is to edit your question to improve it, and hope the community votes to reopen it.